# How to implement document.getElementById in Gatsby(React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to write a function in my Gatsby project.
In normal javascript projects I would use document.getElementById to manipulate an element from the DOM, but how does that way of manipulation work in Gatsby? Can't seem to find any information online.

- When I try to do it in the normal javascript way, I get a warning that says my variable is assigned a value, but it's never used. Any way to fix this?

Comment: It's React, so you modify the state of the component. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 4):

In Gatsby (like any React project) you can use `document.getElementbyId` function or other DOM functions. However, it's considered bad practice since you are creating a virtual DOM to avoid access to the real DOM due to the huge impact of performance (like jQuery has for instance).

Of course, you are able to use them, but in Gatsby in particular, since it's prerendering your project and functions/logic before some global objects are created, it may cause severe issues. Most of that issues are explained in [Debugging HTML Builds](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/) (from Gatsby's official documentation). In other words, `window` or `document` may not be created at the moment your function is requesting them.

You can avoid those issues by using a React lifecycle (`componentDidMount` or `useEffect` hook) because they wait until the DOM tree is generated to be triggered.

Answering your question; if you want to avoid the usage of a high-impact DOM function, you should use React's `ref`.

```
const Post= ({ data }) => {
  const postReference = useRef(null),

  return <Layout>
      <div ref={postReference} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
};
```

In this dummy example, `postReference.current` will have exactly the same information as `document.getElementById(postId)`. And it has a low performance impact.

If you still want to use `document.getElementById` function, you should do something like:

```
const Post= ({ data }) => {
  useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(document.getElementById("myPost"))
  }, []):

  return <Layout>
      <div id="myPost" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.html }} />
};
```

References: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

> When I try to do it in the normal javascript way, I get a warning that
> says my variable is assigned a value, but it's never used. Any way to
> fix this?

You can ignore those warnings, but I would suggest to don't do it, if you are not using a variable, remove it to improve your code performance. They appear due to ESLint configuration. To remove it you just need to find `.eslintrc.json` in your root folder and remove this line: `"no-unused-vars": "warn"`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a super-dirty hack that can help you if you need to get it working fast:

```
const docRef = typeof document !== `undefined` ? document : undefined;
if (!docRef) { return };
```